# How To Prevent More Than One showOpenDialog Window In Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I am calling simple [showOpenDialog](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) system dialog in Electron when button clicked in renderer window.

The issue is that new `showOpenDialog` popup opens on top of old ones when button clicked more than once.

How can I focus on the firstly opened dialog and not allow to reopen new dialogs if there is already opened one?

Preferably when `showOpenDialog` is already opened, it should block the calling renderer process window until the dialog popup is closed. Similar behavior already having [dialog.showMessageBox](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/dialog.md#dialogshowmessageboxbrowserwindow-options-callback)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this for Mac OS via adding "sheet" style dialog.

More info from ["Electron API Demos"](https://github.com/electron/electron-api-demos):

[image]

Didn't test on Win / Lin OS`es, so behavior is unknown there.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to only have one dialog pop up at a time. Hopefully it helps.

```
 <div id="filePath" name="file">None</div>
 <input type="button" value="Select File" onclick="selectFile()">

<script>
const { dialog } = require('electron').remote;
function selectFile(){
dialog.showOpenDialog({properties: ['openFile']}, 
  function (path) {
      //see file name in console
      console.log(path);
      //save info to a div and var if needed
      file = path; 
      document.getElementById("filePath").innerText = file;
  }
);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this code under main.js file

```
let mainWindow = null;
const isSecondInstance = app.makeSingleInstance((commandLine, workingDirectory) => {
  if (mainWindow) {
      if (mainWindow.isMinimized()) mainWindow.restore()
      mainWindow.focus()
  }
})

if (isSecondInstance) {
  app.quit()
}
```

Comment: The question talks about showOpenDialog and not electron window